# Amazon SNS did not deliver the message from lambda trigger

Tags: aws-lambda, sms, amazon-sns

I have written the below lambda code to send SMS. The SMS was created, but SMS did not deliver to the devices. I guess It got stuck in either SNS Queue or Lambda trigger queue.

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sns = new AWS.SNS();

exports.handler = async (event, callback) => {
  if (!event.request.session || event.request.session.length === 0) {
    const phone = event.request.userAttributes.phone_number
    const otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
    const message = "OTP to login to Stable is "+otp

    sns.publish({
        Message: message,
        MessageAttributes: {
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
                DataType: 'String',
                StringValue: 'Transactional'
            },
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
                DataType: 'String',
                StringValue: 'sender'
            },
        },
        PhoneNumber: phone
    }).promise()
        .then(data => {
            console.log("Sent message to", phone);
            callback(null, data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Sending failed", err);
            callback(err);
        });


    event.response.privateChallengeParameters = {
      answer: otp
    };
    event.response.challengeMetadata = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE";

  }
  console.log('raja');
  console.log(event);
  return event;
};
```

How do I receive the message in the device? Is there any configuration is missing  ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? You also have `return event` which might be returning before your SNS callback is complete

Comment: Hi.Thanks. I moved the return event inside the promise and it works great.

Comment: No problem, added an answer so we can mark this as complete

Answer (score 0):

`return event;` line is returning before the SNS callback is complete, @kulls confirmed that removing this line fixed the issue